# Python/dict2xml : TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, xml

When I try to convert a python dictionary to XML with dict2xml, I have this error :

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

This is my code :

```
import dict2xml
docs = {
    {
        'Id': '30',
        'File': 'Overstock_com-US_Catalog_NonMedia.xml.gz',
        'Section': 'beauty',
        'name': 'Overstock.com',
        'Logo': 'overstock.png',
        'FtpId': '91567',
        'Pool': 'CJ'
    },
    {
        'Id': '31',
        'File': 'Zappos_com-Product_Catalog_1.xml.gz',
        'Section': 'beauty',
        'name': 'Zappos.com',
        'Logo': 'zappos.png',
        'FtpId': '91567',
        'Pool': 'CJ'
    }
}

print(dict2xml(docs, 'add'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to store dicts in a set which is not possible because sets can only contain hashable items(immutable).

Use a list of dicts instead:

```
[{
        'Id': '30',
        'File': 'Overstock_com-US_Catalog_NonMedia.xml.gz',
        'Section': 'beauty',
        'name': 'Overstock.com',
        'Logo': 'overstock.png',
        'FtpId': '91567',
        'Pool': 'CJ'
 },
 {
        'Id': '31',
        'File': 'Zappos_com-Product_Catalog_1.xml.gz',
        'Section': 'beauty',
        'name': 'Zappos.com',
        'Logo': 'zappos.png',
        'FtpId': '91567',
        'Pool': 'CJ'
 }
]
```

Comment: @Haidro that comment made a lot of sense!